# Screenshot programmatically and blur in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, screenshot, blur

I want to take a screenshot from my app programmatically and the code working fine but I have a UIVisualEffectView with blur effect and the screenshot gave me the image without blur!
How I can make the screenshot take the blur also?

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(fullView.bounds.size, true, 1)
self.fullView.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext())
var viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(viewImage, nil, nil, nil)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After taking a screenshot, a blur effect can be added programmatically. Here's an example of using the [GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage) library, which can be installed using [CocoaPods](http://cocoapods.org/?q=GPUImage). A similar effect can also be achieved using native Apple libraries.

```
GPUImagePicture *picture = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:snapShot];
GPUImageiOSBlurFilter *blurFilter = [[GPUImageiOSBlurFilter alloc] init];
[blurFilter setBlurRadiusInPixels:4];

[picture addTarget:blurFilter];
[blurFilter useNextFrameForImageCapture];
[picture processImage];

UIImage *processed = [blurFilter imageFromCurrentFramebuffer];
```

Answer (score 4):

To retain the UIVisualEffectView Blur when taking an image of the screen programmatically, you must be taking an image of the entire screen.

Here is a more technical definition provided by Apple:

> Many effects require support from the window that hosts the
>   UIVisualEffectView. Attempting to take a snapshot of only the
>   UIVisualEffectView will result in a snapshot that does not contain the
>   effect. To take a snapshot of a view hierarchy that contains a
>   UIVisualEffectView, you must take a snapshot of the entire UIWindow or
>   UIScreen that contains it. - [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIVisualEffectView/index.html)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, is there any other way to add the blur effect to part of the screen when I take the screenshot even without the UIVisualEffectView?

Comment: @BandarAljahmi I added an example of how to blur an image programmatically, though this should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem. I had a view controller with a visual effect (blur) applied to a background image and some other non-blurred view on top and I wanted to take a screenshot of that controller.

As highlighted by @user3721428 trying to capture the view doesn't work. For my surprise trying to render the window layer in context doesn't work.

What worked is to get a snapshotView from UIScreen:
`let view = UIScreen.main.snapshotView(afterScreenUpdates: true)`

And then grab an image from that view using a method [like in @neave answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43467495/4659547)