# How do you make a screenshot of an image made programmatically ? (swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage, screenshot

After retrieving an image from Parse and creating an UIImageView in the main storyboard, I did a screenshot of the view (DraggablePhoto) containing the UIImageView, by using the following scheme:

```
var view = MDCSwipeToChooseView(frame: self.DraggablePhoto.bounds, options: options)

    let imageori = UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.DraggablePhoto.bounds.size)
    let imageori1 = self.DraggablePhoto.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    var screenShot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    image = screenShot

    view.imageView.image = image
```

Problem is the UIImageView included in the DraggablePhoto view does not appear on the screenshot, knowing that the uiimageview includes a retrieved image from Parse...

My question is: Why is the screenshot not showing this image knowing that everything else is properly shown?
How do you solve this problem? Please note I am a beginner.

EDIT: I found the solution to my problem.
Just keep in mind that when you retrieve a file(i.e. picture) from Parse you need to make sure the screenshot function can access/be related with the line of code that matches the UIimageView with the image file...
What I did is I called the screenshot func inside the .getDataInBackgroundWithBlock from Parse (not sure if this is a nice way to do it as I am still a beginner but it does the job on my screen)

Comment: In what function is the above code located?

Comment: Here is question like yours http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25448879/how-to-take-full-screen-screenshot-in-swift

Comment: in  override func viewDidLoad()  , and Pixele9 please note my UIImageView includes an image that is taken from Parse . Are you sure the replies to the other question are of any help?