# Why is my screenshot not displaying current view?

Tags: swift

When I take a screenshot to share the current view of my device (iPhone), it only takes the upper part of it, and when I scroll down to the bottom (of my tableview at runtime), the screenshot is blank as if not capturing the current view on the device - I hope I am explaining alright there.

Am I missing anything?

```
func captureScreen() -> UIImage {

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.bounds.size, false, 0);
    self.view.drawViewHierarchyInRect(view.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
    let image:UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return image
}
```

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25448879/how-to-take-full-screen-screenshot-in-swift

Comment: Not sure if related, but are you aware of the difference between `bounds` and `frame`? It might be that in one of the methods you should use `frame` instead.

Comment: I think it should be `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.frame.size, false, 1)`

Comment: It was indeed a case of replacing `bounds` with `frame`. Thank you, guys! Is there a way to accept your answers? I can't see the checkmark.

Comment: They are just comments, not answers! Therefore you cannot accept one ;) Glad to help

Comment: Much appreciated :)!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change your code to the following :

```
func captureScreen() -> UIImage {

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.frame.size, false, 0);
self.view.drawViewHierarchyInRect(view.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
let image:UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

return image
```

}

Note the change from bound to frame in your code. The last argument in `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` has to do with the scale. `If you specify a value of 0.0, the scale factor is set to the scale factor of the device’s main screen`

Learn more about it [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/#//apple_ref/c/func/UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions)