# Swift - snapshot of ListView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Can someone please tell me how to take a snapshot from a listView?

First I thought that a screenshot will do the job, but sometimes the listView is bigger and it will be good to take a snapshot from it instead.

Comment: follow this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25448879/how-to-take-full-screen-screenshot-in-swift/25457222#25457222)

Answer (score 2):

You can take a snapshot from any `UIView` like this:

```
let snapshot = myView.snapshotView(afterScreenUpdates: true)
```