# Screenshot of ARSCNView

Tags: ios, swift, arkit

I need to make a screenshot of ARSCNView, the class is defined as below:

```
public class SceneLocationView: ARSCNView, ARSCNViewDelegate { }
```

I am following the below methods to have the screenshot done:
[How do I take a full screen Screenshot in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25448879/how-do-i-take-a-full-screen-screenshot-in-swift)

but the scenelocationview view is not printed, all the rest is.

Anyone was able to do this successfully ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is also another way:

`ARSCNView` has a built in function: `.snapshot()`

This can be called easily like so:

```
  let renderedImage = augmentedRealityView.snapshot()
```

And it may also be more useful as I believe that it doesn't render any `UIKit` elements such as `UINavigationBar` as well.

Answer (score 3):

Try this extension,

```
extension UIView {
    var snapshot: UIImage? {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(bounds.size, false, 0)
        defer { UIGraphicsEndImageContext() }
        drawHierarchy(in: bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
        return UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    }
}
```

and use

```
let screenShot = self.view?.snapshot
```

I was able to save the screenshot of OpenGL View from this extension.

Comment: That worked like a charm! Thanks a lot for that. Do you have any idea how to hide toolbar with your extension? Thanks again.

Comment: you want to hide toolbar before taking screen shot ?

Comment: I want to take the screenshot without having the toolbar. If the only way to do so is to hide it i will do and then wet it visible again, but please let me know if that is the only way you know to achieve it. Thanks.