# Text View Screenshot in Swift?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitextview

I found a source code about view screenshot. I changed it a little and tried. But this code has a little problem. Screenshot resolution is really bad. I need a good resolution screenshot. I tried to add a comment, but I'm new on stackoverflow. Anyway, what can I do for this ?

Link : [Screenshot in swift iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25444609/screenshot-in-swift-ios)

My code :

```
func textViewSS() {
    //Create the UIImage
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(textView.frame.size)
    textView.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext())
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    //Save it to the camera roll
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil)
}
```

Sample Result :
http://i60.tinypic.com/s4wdn4.png

Comment: What is a textview screen shot?

Comment: Are you saying you want to save the textview as a photo?

Comment: I edited my question. Sorry for my bad explanation. Please look at this link : http://i60.tinypic.com/s4wdn4.png

Comment: What is the error you are getting from running this?

Comment: I am not getting error. Just I'm getting bad resolution in screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Trying modifying the first line in your code to pass the scale if you are not satisfied with the resolution

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(textView.frame.size, false, UIScreen.mainScreen().scale)
```

I don't know the requirement in your case but `drawViewHierarchyInRect` is quicker/cheaper than `renderInContext`. You may want to consider that if it is applicable.

Comment: Oh that worked ! Thanks. Well, Is this make the screenshot size big ?

Comment: Glad it worked :). Yes it would make the size big.. you can try playing around with number values 1,1.5 etc to see if a satisfactory resolution with lesser size..   [Don't forget to accept the answer ;-)]

Comment: ok, got it. I have a new question then :) I created a small textview. I want to put a write range limit. How can I do ?

Comment: This works well ! :)  But I need for textview size limit. When the text out of textview and scroll comes up, then stop. This code just gives me char limit. Right ?