# Programmatically Screenshot | Swift 3, macOS

Tags: swift, macos, screenshot

Is it possible to take a screenshot programmatically of the desktop on mac using Swift 3?
I can't find a single thread or forum post about the topic, not even in apple's official documentation.

I have found this so far but it doesn't seem to help: [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25448879/how-do-i-take-a-full-screen-screenshot-in-swift) [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25444609/screenshot-in-swift-ios)

Comment: for security and privacy reason it is highly considerable from both developers and users' perspectives.

Comment: Yes I understand but I have no intentions of releasing this software it is rather for learning and in-house deploent purposes and I would be fine if a little "accept screenshot" window would appear.

Comment: `NSTask` - `screencapture`

Comment: @vadian Can you point me to a sample code or documentation or some other useful source regarding "NSTask - screen capture"

Comment: `NSTask` is the Cocoa class to run command line interfaces - `screencapture` is the command line interface to make screenshots

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Yes its possible. This function takes all connected monitors screenshots and writes to specified path as jpg file. Generates file name as unix time stamp.

```
 func TakeScreensShots(folderName: String){
    
    var displayCount: UInt32 = 0;
    var result = CGGetActiveDisplayList(0, nil, &displayCount)
    if (result != CGError.success) {
        print("error: \(result)")
        return
    }
    let allocated = Int(displayCount)
    let activeDisplays = UnsafeMutablePointer<CGDirectDisplayID>.allocate(capacity: allocated)
    result = CGGetActiveDisplayList(displayCount, activeDisplays, &displayCount)
    
    if (result != CGError.success) {
        print("error: \(result)")
        return
    }
       
    for i in 1...displayCount {
        let unixTimestamp = CreateTimeStamp()
        let fileUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: folderName + "\(unixTimestamp)" + "_" + "\(i)" + ".jpg", isDirectory: true)
        let screenShot:CGImage = CGDisplayCreateImage(activeDisplays[Int(i-1)])!
        let bitmapRep = NSBitmapImageRep(cgImage: screenShot)
        let jpegData = bitmapRep.representation(using: NSBitmapImageRep.FileType.jpeg, properties: [:])!
        
        
        do {
            try jpegData.write(to: fileUrl, options: .atomic)
        }
        catch {print("error: \(error)")}
    }
}

func CreateTimeStamp() -> Int32
{
    return Int32(Date().timeIntervalSince1970)
}
```

Comment: I didn't check your code yet but it looks like quality, unlike the way I solved it using scripts and terminal. I didn't expect any answers after so long.

Comment: It works, it's a really nice implementation handles multiple displays.

Comment: @B.Tekkan @Magrafear I get an error CreateTimeStamp(): `let unixTimestamp = CreateTimeStamp()` "use of unresolved identifier 'CreateTimeSpan'"

Comment: Just create a function for CreateTimeStamp() that returns Date() or NSDate() as a string formatted how you need.

Comment: CreateTimeStamp() method just creates a uniq name for the file. I add the method for you.

Answer (score 14):

```
let displayID = CGMainDisplayID()
let imageRef = CGDisplayCreateImage(displayID)
```