# How can i take screen shot from a portion of mac display with swift?

Tags: swift, macos

I wanted to know how is it possible to take a screen shot from a portion of mac display for example from point(100,200) till point(400,600) with swift?

Answer (score 1):

See `CGWindowListCreateImage` – or call `/usr/sbin/screencapture` (possibly [using a framework](https://github.com/nirix/swift-screencapture)) and crop the result.

Comment: thanks for your input i found the way i will post the answer

Answer (score 0):

based on the answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/40864231/1288164
i added a CGRect to CGDisplayCreateImage:

```
let rect = CGRect(x: yourOriginX, y: yourOriginY, width: yourWidth, height :yourHeight);
 let screenShot:CGImage = CGDisplayCreateImage(activeDisplays[Int(i-1)],rect: rect)!
```