# How to take a screenshot of your entire screen

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

I have created an Xcode swift based software that is menu based. One of the buttons I have created is intended to capture a screenshot and save the file to a specific location.

I have found sources explaining how to do this on iOS, but I'm looking for macOS functionality. The article: [Programmatically Screenshot | Swift 3, macOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39691106/programmatically-screenshot-swift-3-macos) has responses that have gotten me close but I think some of it is deprecated.

How can I implement this in a software developed for macOS with Xcode & Swift 5.

Here is the code for the function:

```
@objc func TakeScreenshot(_ sender: Any){

    func CreateTimeStamp() -> Int32
    {
        return Int32(Date().timeIntervalSince1970)
    }

    var displayCount: UInt32 = 0;
        var result = CGGetActiveDisplayList(0, nil, &displayCount)
        if (result != CGError.success) {
            print("error: \(result)")
            return
        }
        let allocated = Int(displayCount)
        let activeDisplays = UnsafeMutablePointer<CGDirectDisplayID>.allocate(capacity: allocated)
        result = CGGetActiveDisplayList(displayCount, activeDisplays, &displayCount)

        if (result != CGError.success) {
            print("error: \(result)")
            return
        }

        for i in 1...displayCount {
            let unixTimestamp = CreateTimeStamp()
            let fileUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: "~/Documents" + "\(unixTimestamp)" + "_" + "\(i)" + ".jpg", isDirectory: true)
            let screenShot:CGImage = CGDisplayCreateImage(activeDisplays[Int(i-1)])!
            let bitmapRep = NSBitmapImageRep(cgImage: screenShot)
            let jpegData = bitmapRep.representation(using: NSBitmapImageRep.FileType.jpeg, properties: [:])!


            do {
                try jpegData.write(to: fileUrl, options: .atomic)
            }
            catch {print("error: \(error)")}
        }

}


 menu.addItem(NSMenuItem(title: "Take Screenshot", action:
            #selector(AppDelegate.TakeScreenshot(_:)), keyEquivalent: ""))
```

The second portion of code is the menu item that is a button. I want this button to take a screenshot of the screen and then save the file to a location I specify.

I get this error when I use the button on my application:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Hdtx.png)

Comment: Welcome Alex! You wrote _have gotten me close_ - show us the code with an explanation what's wrong, what doesn't work, etc. I'd highly recommend to visit the help center and read about [mre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), [good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), ... The more info you provide, the better & faster we can help.

Comment: Thanks! Just updated my original post with code. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: In the future, please don't post images of text, post the text as text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error has to do with saving the file. You are constructing the URL badly.

First, expanding `~` to the home directory is generally a shell feature, not an OS feature. The underlying file path APIs (e.g. `open()`) just treat that as a normal character in a path. Foundation does support expanding `~` in path **strings** (not URLs), but you have to specifically request it with `expandingTildeInPath`. It's never automatic and it's never meaningful in URLs.

Next, I suspect you were trying to build a URL to a file within the Documents directory. However, you did not put a path separator (`/`) between the name of the directory and the name of the file. In other words, you constructed `~/Documents10989439875_1.jpg`, not `~/Documents/10989439875_1.jpg`.

You should use `FileManager().urls(for:.downloadsDirectory, in:.userDomainMask)[0]` to get the URL to the Downloads folder and then append a path component to that using `appendingPathComponent(_:isDirectory:)`.

Comment: Thanks Ken! I tried your suggestions and heres what I got:

I created `let dirPath = FileManager().urls(for:.downloadsDirectory, in:.userDomainMask)[0]` and `let downloadDir = dirPath.appendingPathComponent(_:isDirectory:)` under my TakeScreenshot function. Then where I had `"~/Documents"` I replaced with `downloadDir`. 

 I am now getting a "Cannot convert value of type 'URL' to expected argument type 'String'". I am not too sure on how to implement what you recommended but I tried it this way and cant seem to find the correct way. PS: Sorry for formatting

Comment: It's not quite clear exactly what the new code looks like. You could edit into your question. But, I think you should replace the `let fileUrl ...` line with `let fileUrl = dirPath.appendingPathComponent("\(unixTimestamp)" + "_" + "\(i)" + ".jpg", isDirectory:false)`. You shouldn't need the `downloadDir` variable, as near as I can see.

Comment: Thanks! This worked perfectly. Makes sense now how to make it work.