# How to add interactive UILabels on top of a UIImageView?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uilabel, interactive

I need to add few labels on top of an `UIImageView`. The labels' text can be changed by tapping on them. What is the best way to achieve this? I am using Swift programming language. Looking up some solutions on stackoverflow, I found a couple of walkthroughs that use `String.drawInRect` method to draw some text in a rectangle which is then placed on the `UIImageView`. But like this I don't think I will be able to change the text, or even recognize a touch event on them. Please help.

**UPDATE**

My code so far:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let img = UIImage(named: "Image")
    let imgView = UIImageView(image: img)

    self.view.addSubview(imgView)

    var myLabel = UILabel()
    myLabel.text = "Hello There"
    myLabel.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
    myLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Marker Felt", size: 20)
    myLabel.accessibilityIdentifier = "this is good!"
    myLabel.frame = CGRect(x: img!.size.width/2 /* - myLable.width / 2 ? */, y: 0, width: img!.size.width, height: 40)
    imgView.addSubview(myLabel)
    imgView.userInteractionEnabled = true
    myLabel.userInteractionEnabled = true
    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handlePanGesture:")
    myLabel.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
}

func handlePanGesture(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    var senderView = sender.view as! UILabel
    print(senderView.text)
    senderView.text = "look how i changed!"
    print(senderView.accessibilityIdentifier)
}
```

So far the results are positive I have an image with the label on top of it that can respond to touch events. Now I need to find the label's width so that I can effectively place it in the center when required. Then I need to find a way to place the labels at exact coordinates relative to the image's top left corner as origin.

Any help in these two tasks will be hugely appreciated.

Comment: you can add gestureRecegonizers

Comment: Use https://github.com/null09264/FRHyperLabel which select specific text from label. Use Label on Image.It will work.it comes in both ObjC and Swift

Comment: @GaneshKumar can you be more elaborative?

Comment: @JadeSync either you can use buttons which has inbuilt action or you can use labels with gesture recognizer to add actions for the labels.

Comment: @GaneshKumar I understand that. But how can I overlay these labels on an uiimage? at given coordinates that are relative to the image's (0,0)?

Comment: @JadeSync what have you done sofar? you haven't given any code and yet you are asking how to do that?

Comment: @GaneshKumar Updated the question with my codes

Comment: @JadeSync how do you want to place the label on top of the imageview? and the width should be equal to the imageview?

Comment: @JadeSync did you update your question with some Screen that we can easily understand what is your actual problem .

Comment: @JadeSync When you tap on the label, you just make it editable with tap gesture and with pan gesture you can move it on imageview

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya

Comment: @JadeSync please put some screen in your question

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya  am close to finding a solution right now. I'll update as soon as I finish it.

Comment: @JadeSync i got your solution you just need tap label frame right then i just update it see my answer .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Adding label on `ImageView`  is best approach. but you can also do it by adding `button` on `ImageView`.

I created a example where i created a `ImageView` on storyboard and create its outlet in ViewController class and in `viewDidLoad` i created a label and add it to label and add `UITapGestureRecognizer` to label.  when user taps label we changed the label text and it's position.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

 @IBOutlet weak var winterImageView: UIImageView!

 override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()

  let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 0, width: self.winterImageView.frame.width - 10, height: 30))
  label.textColor = UIColor.redColor()

  label.userInteractionEnabled = true
  let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handleTap(_:)))
  label.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
  label.text = "Is Winter is coming, My Friend?"
  self.winterImageView.addSubview(label)

}
```

[image]

Change label text and position in `handleTap`

```
 /// handle tap here 
 func handleTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

  let senderView = sender.view as! UILabel
senderView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
NSLayoutConstraint(item: senderView, attribute: .CenterX, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.winterImageView, attribute: .CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0).active = true

NSLayoutConstraint(item: senderView, attribute: .CenterY, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.winterImageView, attribute: .CenterY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0).active = true
 print(senderView.text)
senderView.text = "Yes!!! Winter is coming, My Friend!!"

}
```

[image]

You can download project from here [InteractiveLabel](https://github.com/Sahilberi/InteractiveLabel)

Comment: @MicroR you can try by taking screenshot of the image http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25444609/screenshot-in-swift-ios

Answer (score 2):

I can see from the other answers and comments related to one another virtually same stuff.If you familiar using Cocoa pods then you will agree with my opinion.Always,Just look around yourself and pick the best.If you want your project goes smooth and steady then **JLStickerTextView** is your friend and its way to go.It's free,elegant and more vibrant label customisation project available to everyone and the best thing about this project is written in handy **Swift**.

**Github Link**: https://github.com/luiyezheng/JLStickerTextView

**Features**

- You can add multiple Text to StickerTextView at the same time
- Multiple line Text support
- Rotate, resize the text with one finger
- Set the Color, alpha, font, alignment, TextShadow, lineSpacing...... of the text
- StickerTextView also handle the process of rendering text on Image
  Written in Swift

**Note:** In, My personal opinion.Way, the code been written in this projects simply superb and properly categorised.

**Avaliable Text Attributes Reference:**

[image]

MainView Screenshot from the project:

[image]

Output from my personal project based on JLStickerTextView.I, hope you will consider it.If you need any more information let me know...

[image]

Comment: in this i got it error can you solve it https://github.com/luiyezheng/JLStickerTextView/issues/10

Comment: stickerImageView.swift file

Comment: Just comment out  `stickerView.limitImageViewToSuperView()` from your mainVC and set your `stickerImageView` content mode to `aspectToFit` or `aspectToFill` as the forum recommended or code yourself(pretty easy to do)

Comment: can u provide example in swift 3

Comment: what do you mean?. stickerView will work after you convert to `Current Swift Syntex` . I believe you getting 85+ syntax error after you converted to Swift 3. you have to manually fix all of them.I know its a pain in the bm...

Comment: dont comment empty handed?. tell me whats error r you getting. may be i can help. if you show me something ?

Comment: i can't rotate sticker(Label) nd close and rotate buttons are not shown

Comment: have you set image to your button(close & rotate)....i thing button won't comes with the project or may be is not visible?. I want to make it clear.stickerView project is not a easy or straight forward project...you need to workout many things to achieve what you after.it could take about a week?.You could implement new idea to the project once you fully understand the project....so take it easy , be patients? and stretch your time...

Comment: stickerView.currentlyEditingLabel.tintColor = UIColor.red
        stickerView.currentlyEditingLabel.rotateView?.image = UIImage(named: "rotate_img")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
        stickerView.currentlyEditingLabel.closeView!.image = UIImage(named: "cancel_img")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
nd

Comment: where you setting above code? .code should go inside your button action method should work and i want you to comment clearly as my time is limited:(

Comment: you dont need to set anything for rotate...project comes with that func by default....how you trying in `sim or iPhone?`

Comment: is user Intraction enabled on stickerViewImage?

Comment: how  can i use custom font in this? means external font apply in this

Comment: follow this post to use custom font to your project. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40168344/xcode-8-custom-font-doesnt-show-up-in-interface-builder/40170579#40170579  from my answer try `step1 and 2`  make sure `upvote` before you proceed or further comment?

Comment: but @Joe in this they Error in "adjustsWidthToFillItsContens" method they UIFont is nil return so they crash

Comment: they don't found custom font

Comment: custom font won't give you a crash. font simply won't work if you not set them up properly?... comment clearly how/where you getting the error?. i can't spend time for nothing.please respect my time?

Comment: hey this normal label ok but  i want to use in JLStickerTextView in custom fonts

Comment: what you mean did you look at the link?......`JLStickertextView` nothing to do with `custom font` ....font set by the `Xcode`?......Import custom font to your project -> update plist with font array -> update font name in `fontNamesArray` thats simple?

Comment: @ItsMeMihir I was facing same issue have you solved your Issue ? and could you please help me with this?

Comment: @KhushbuDesai still I can’t get solution for that

Comment: @ItsMeMihir :p i was thinking to solving errors , thanks for saving my time. have you found any alternative for this feature? i need to implement it in my Photo Editing app.

Comment: @KhushbuDesai I think i found the way to do it  while ago. but, I am not using this project anymore...so, i recommend you to give a request to the author or see any updates available...

Comment: @ItsMeMihir  https://github.com/khush004/StickerView/tree/master here is code of JLStickerTextView which is error free with compatibility of swift 3.0

Comment: @KhushbuDesai Good Job

Answer (score 2):

> [github.com/khush004/StickerView/tree/master](http://github.com/khush004/StickerView/tree/master)

here is code of JLStickerTextView which is error free with compatibility of swift 3.0

Answer (score 1):

You can use a label and add a gesture recognizer from which you can set an action.

EDIT (responding to OP comment) :

Basically you put an UILabel on top of your card, set a gesture recognizer on it, and set a hidden UITextField at the same position as your label. This way when you tap on it, you specify in your gesture recognizer method that the UI must set label as hidden and textfield as visible. When you're done (end editing), just save your changes and update the UI.

Comment: But how do I overlay that label over an UIImage? For example, suppose the image is background image of a visiting card and the labels are the textual fields in it. How do I make it so the users see what appears to be a normal visiting card but they should be able to update fields by tapping on them?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to center align your UILabel and UIImageView, you can use AutoLayout constraint.

```
NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: .CenterX, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: imageView, attribute: .CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0).active = true

NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: .CenterY, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: imageView, attribute: .CenterY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0).active = true
```

Answer (score 1):

```
func handlePanGesture(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
       let senderView = sender.view as! UILabel
       print(senderView.text)
        senderView.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
       senderView.text = "look how i changed!"
       print(senderView.accessibilityIdentifier)
    }
```

Ouput :

**sender.view?.frame**

▿ Optional
  ▿ Some : CGRect
    ▿ origin : CGPoint
      - x : 0.0
      - y : 0.0 { ... }
    ▿ size : CGSize
      - width : 335.0
      - height : 28.0

Answer (score 1):

I use CALayers, gesture recognizers, and the hitTest method of the layers. Sample code below:

```
class ImageView: UIImageView {

    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer()

    let redLayer = CATextLayer()
    var redHitCounter:Int = 0
    let greenLayer = CATextLayer()
    var greenHitCounter:Int = 0

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setUpClickableLayers()
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setUpClickableLayers()
    }

    private func setUpClickableLayers() {

        self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

        tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        tapGesture.addTarget(self, action: #selector(changeText))
        self.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

        redLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 40, y: 40, width: 100, height: 40)
        redLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        redLayer.string = String(redHitCounter)
        redLayer.alignmentMode = kCAAlignmentCenter
        self.layer.addSublayer(redLayer)

        greenLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 40, y: 140, width: 100, height: 40)
        greenLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
        greenLayer.string = String(redHitCounter)
        greenLayer.alignmentMode = kCAAlignmentCenter
        self.layer.addSublayer(greenLayer)
    }

    internal func changeText(_ recognizer:UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        let p = recognizer.location(in: self)
        if (redLayer.hitTest(p) != nil) {
            redHitCounter += 1
            redLayer.string = String(redHitCounter)
        } else if (greenLayer.hitTest(p) != nil) {
            greenHitCounter += 1
            greenLayer.string = String(greenHitCounter)
        }
    }
}
```

A few notes:

(1) Remember to set your UIImageView's isUserInteractionEnabled to true. It took me an hour to debug why my UIImageView was seeing gestures!

(2) The hitTest() method works for the CALayer and all subclasses. Just remember to make the layer large enough to work on fat fingers.

(3) You can also use the pan and pinch gestures to move, rotate, and resize the target layer.