# How to save screenshot of a view with its subviews in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, calayer, screen-capture

I want to capture a view with its subviews. I'm using this code to capture the screen:

```
let view = self.faceTrackerContainerView

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(view.bounds.size.width, view.bounds.size.height))
UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
self.view?.drawViewHierarchyInRect(view.frame, afterScreenUpdates: true)
let screenshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(screenshot, nil, nil, nil)
```

These codes capture the whole screen including a button that's in front of the view. I tried these codes but it only captures the main view excluding its subviews:

```
let view = self.faceTrackerContainerView
let scale = UIScreen.mainScreen().scale
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, false, scale);

view.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
let screenshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(screenshot, nil, nil, nil)
```

I also tried the `snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates(true)` from here but I don't know how to implement it. I have a collectionView below the view and a button on top of the view (both are not in the view). The first codes capture everything with the button, collectionView, and subviews. The second codes capture the view without the subviews. What am I missing?

Comment: all subviews you want to capture are visible on screen?

Comment: Yes, they are. I think I'll just hide the views I don't want in the screenshot and put it back in after.

Answer (score 17):

This is working for me,

```
func screenShotMethod() {
    //Create the UIImage
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(faceTrackerContainerView.frame.size)
    faceTrackerContainerView.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    //Save it to the camera roll
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil)
}
```

[Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25445629/3411787)

Comment: Hi. Thanks for this. This is also where I got the codes and it's capturing everything in my screen. I just want to capture a view with its subview though.

Comment: Try changing `view` with `self.faceTrackerContainerView` from above code.

Comment: I've tried that but views down't have the renderInContext method though.

Comment: nice, work 0 problems

Answer (score 10):

```
extension UIView {
    func asImage() -> UIImage {
        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(bounds: bounds)
        return renderer.image { rendererContext in
            layer.render(in: rendererContext.cgContext)
        }
    }
}
```

It makes an UIImage from a UIView. Then you can use that image with UIImageView(image:) method

Answer (score 4):

Why not just call [`snapshotView(afterScreenUpdates:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622531-snapshotview)?

Comment: Thanks for the codes. I'm pretty new at this. Would you mind telling me which parts I need to change/correct?

Comment: @Vinz: I guess mentioned method will return UIView with rendering captured view, not direct UIImage - you want to store in PhotosAlbum

Comment: I tried using it but can't get it to work. Gave me a blank in one of my tries.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't very elegant, but hiding views before the screenshot is taken works. You can then make them visible afterwards.

```
view.isHidden = true

//screenshot

view.isHidden = false
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Add all subviews(that you want to include in screenshot) to one
   parent view.
2. Draw parent view hierarchy like this:

   > ```
   >   let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: mapParentView.bounds.size)
   >     let image = renderer.image { ctx in
   >        mapParentView.drawHierarchy(in: mapParentView.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
   >       }
   > ```